# How to configure "open next or previous item" after delete in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

How to configure "open next or previous item" after delete in Outlook 2010? I can't find this option.

Need a search within the Options window :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Options, under mail at the very bottom there is an "After moving or deleting an open item:" with a pull down option list that you can choose what to do..

do you not have that?

Comment: Yes I found it. It was somewhere prominent in previous versions, could not locate it in 2010. Thanks Rex.